# Как поместить текст по центру внутри group в svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как поместить текст по центру внутри g?

Вот тут нужно чтобы текст "Текст по центру"
был по центру группы `<g class="point"">`
https://jsfiddle.net/wpvk3c64/4/

Чтобы получилось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть одно но, размеры группы зависят от расположения элементов в ней, по-этому я вынес текст за пределы группы, в остальном алгоритм простой:

Я посчитал точку привязки и расположил текст по центру относительно нее при помощи `text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"`

```js
let bbox = document.querySelector('svg g.point').getBBox();
let text = document.querySelector('svg text');
text.setAttributeNS(null, "x", bbox.x+bbox.width/2);
text.setAttributeNS(null, "y", bbox.y+bbox.height/2);
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
    <g class="point">
      <circle></circle>
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
      <rect x="140" y="10" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
    </g>
    <text font-size=30 fill="red" class="pointIndex" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
      Текст по центру
    </text>
  </svg>
```

PS: можно ничего не считать а отталкиваться от размеров самой `svg`, то есть поставить его по центру самой картинки `<text x="50%" y="50%"`.

Comment: А без программирования как можно реализовать?

Comment: по отнощению к группе - я не знаю такого способа